# Iris Round Transition

Tags: animation, keyframes

I recently began a project and I would like to implement an "Iris Round" transition in Blender. This is where a circle closes in on the frame, almost like at the end of some cartoons. I thought something like this would work:

[image]

It would work if I was able to keyframe in edit mode, but does anybody know how this can be done?
Thanks!

Comment: You could use shapekeys.

Comment: This is probably a lot more practical to achieve in post production in the compositor

Comment: So long as the hole is not completely closed at scale 1, you can animate the scale in object mode, can't you? Or do you need the exterior rectangle to be in shot?